# ReadDwgFile from URL in Autocad I/O

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin, dwg

I try to do a program upload in AUtocad I/O It works good in local but in the cloud i get the message :

```
Error: Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception: eInetFileOpenFailed
[10/03/2017 09:05:07]    at Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Database.ReadDwgFile(String fileName, FileShare fileSharing, Boolean allowCPConversion, String password)
```

I use this code to get the DWG that i need to implement.

```
blockQualifiedFileName = "http://urltoDWG.dwg";
sourceDb.ReadDwgFile(blockQualifiedFileName,
                                     System.IO.FileShare.Read,
                                      true,
"");
```

Can someone help me to understand why this error and how to fix it. Perap's I can upload my file in this cloud to have an access like the job here - >T:\Aces\Jobs\

Best regards

Comment: Ok I find solution to put my dwg file on cloud I did someting like this wi.Arguments.InputArguments.Add(new Argument()
        {
            Name = "DwgAssembly", // Must match the input parameter in activity
            Resource =
            "http://urlTo.dwg",
            StorageProvider = StorageProvider.Generic // Generic HTTP download (vs A360)
        }); Its now loaded I need to access to T:\Aces\Jobs\WORKITEMID\my.dwg But i don't know how to get WorkItemId...

Comment: FIXED : get access of folder AUTOCAD I/O by environement variable -> Path.GetDirectoryName(db.OriginalFileName)